# add multiple objects to swift array in for loop

Tags: arrays, swift

```
for tempExportData in exportDataArray {
    let tmpRegNO:NSString = (tempExportData as AnyObject).object(forKey: kRegisteredNo) as! NSString
    print("tmpRegNO is",tmpRegNO)
    var tmpNoArray:Array = [String]()
    tmpNoArray.append(tmpRegNO as String)
    print("Count is",tmpNoArray.count)
    print("ARRAY is",tmpNoArray)
}
```

I am trying to add string value i.e `tmpRegNO` to the Array `tmpNoArray`.
In this I can able to add only one value to the array at a time.
How to add the next value  to that array when it is looping for second time.

Comment: you need to initialize the array outside the for in loop

Comment: @ReinierMelian thank you so much for your quickest response...

Comment: your welcome, please accept my answer if solves your issue

Comment: I did not notice that small issue,, thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need move the `tempNoArray` initialization outside of your `for in` loop, if not the your array will be initialized once for every item in your `exportDataArray` remaining only the las item as consequence

You need something like **this**

```
var tmpNoArray:Array = [String]()
for tempExportData in exportDataArray{

        if let tmpRegNO = tempExportData[kRegisteredNo] as? String   
        {

        print("tmpRegNO is",tmpRegNO)
        tmpNoArray.append(tmpRegNO as String)

        print("Count is",tmpNoArray.count)
        print("ARRAY is",tmpNoArray)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you have to declare the array before entering the loop.

Your code is very *objectivecish*. This is a *swiftier* version. Don't annotate types the compiler can infer and use key subscription rather than ugly casting to `AnyObject` and `objectForKey:`.

```
var tmpNoArray = [String]()

for tempExportData in exportDataArray {
    let tmpRegNO = tempExportData[kRegisteredNo] as! String
    print("tmpRegNO is",tmpRegNO)

    tmpNoArray.append(tmpRegNO)

    print("Count is",tmpNoArray.count)
    print("ARRAY is",tmpNoArray)
}
```

You can even write the whole expression in one line:

```
let tmpNoArray = exportDataArray.flatMap { $0[kRegisteredNo] as? String }
```